# XamlCompiler error WMC0055: Cannot assign text value 'Help' into property 'Icon' of type 'IconElement'

Tags: xaml, msbuild

I have a C#/XAML project that is building in Visual Studio 2013 without any errors or warnings, but is failing the build when I attempt to run msbuild from the command line (with no parameters in the solution's directory).

The error I'm receiving is:

```
XamlCompiler error WMC0055: Cannot assign text value 'Help' into property 'Icon' of type 'IconElement'
```

The code in question is the following:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Background="#00b2f0">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Help" Label="Help" Click="HelpButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

According to the MSDN docs, assigning the text value to the Icon attribute is valid.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.icon.aspx

Any ideas on why VS and MSDN docs seem to agree that this is not a problem, but msbuild does?

Comment: try adding Icon as its own [SymbolIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx) tag within AppBarButton

Comment: @Musters Could you show me exactly how to do this? I tried and googled it without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Background="#00b2f0">
        <AppBarButton Label="Help" Click="HelpButton_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Help" />
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```